# Too long to get an element (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to get an element from webpage, but Selenium recognizes it only after 8-10 seconds, I want it to be faster, maximum - 3 secs. What could be wrong?

```html
browser.set_page_load_timeout(3)

    try:
        browser.get('https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/cart')
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    try:
        checkout_button = wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_name('checkout'))
        checkout_button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

        try:
            element = wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_id('checkout_email'))
            element.send_keys('somemail@gmail.com')
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
```

Comment: Which element is the one that is taking so long to find?

Comment: @J.Paul checkout_email